# Apply INNER JOIN only if there is a row available otherwise use NULL

Tags: mysql, join

| id | value_id | parent_id | dropdown_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 14945 | 14944 | 57 | 4000 |
| 8 | 14944 | 0 | 56 | bbb |
| 9 | 14943 | 14940 | 59 | comprable |
| 10 | 14942 | 14939 | 59 | comprable |
| 11 | 14940 | 14931 | 58 | 3 |
| 12 | 14939 | 14930 | 58 | 2 |
| 13 | 14931 | 14929 | 57 | 5000 |
| 14 | 14930 | 14928 | 57 | 4000 |
| 15 | 14929 | 0 | 56 | rrr |
| 16 | 14928 | 0 | 56 | ttt |

I have above table with data. I an using below query to get data from the table.

```
SELECT `d0`.`name` AS `name0`,
       `d1`.`name` AS `name1`,
       `d2`.`name` AS `name2`,
       `d3`.`name` AS `name3`
FROM   `my_table_1` AS `d0`
       INNER JOIN `my_table_1` AS `d1`
               ON d1.parent_id = d0.value_id
       INNER JOIN `my_table_1` AS `d2`
               ON d2.parent_id = d1.value_id
       INNER JOIN `my_table_1` AS `d3`
               ON d3.parent_id = d2.value_id
WHERE  ( d0.dropdown_id = 56 )
```

Here I am using inner join to get `value_id` from its `parent_id`.

Basically, it will check if there is a parent available for current record and will get its data if any. I can get correct data if I have as number of parents for a record as the number of `INNER JOIN`

Like with above query I get details like

| name0 | name1 | name2 | name3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ttt | 4000 | 2 | comprable |
| rrr | 5000 | 3 | comprable |

Here I want to get below table

| name0 | name1 | name2 | name3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ttt | 4000 | 2 | comprable |
| rrr | 5000 | 3 | comprable |
| bbb | 4000 | NULL | NULL |

Here in last row, I do not have `d2` and `d3` tables available. I want to include that data too with `NULL` value.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you replace the inner joins with left joins you will get the data that you want. The left join shows the results even with there is not a match on the other side and in those cases shows a null.

```
SELECT `d0`.`name` AS `name0`,
       `d1`.`name` AS `name1`,
       `d2`.`name` AS `name2`,
       `d3`.`name` AS `name3`
FROM   `my_table_1` AS `d0`
       LEFT JOIN `my_table_1` AS `d1`
              ON d1.parent_id = d0.value_id
       LEFT JOIN `my_table_1` AS `d2`
              ON d2.parent_id = d1.value_id
       LEFT JOIN `my_table_1` AS `d3`
              ON d3.parent_id = d2.value_id
WHERE  ( d0.dropdown_id = 56 )
```

Answer (score 10):

Use a **Left Join** instead of an **Inner Join**.

An **Inner Join** will only give you rows that match from *both* the left *and* right table.

A **Left Join** will return all records from the left table and matching records from the right table. Where there are no matches from the right table, NULLs will appear in place of the right table columns, instead.

Comment: Using outer joins doesn't quite solve this issue. A null from the table that may not have a row in it only tells you that none of its rows match.